# There is any way to save data even app reinstall on ios without keychain?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uninstallation

I want to save some data even after app uninstalls and installed again.
I don't want to use keychain because of some reason personally.

Or Is there any way to get unique key per device like UUID ? or per device per app ?(From ios 10 )

Could you help me, please?

Comment: That's the only way I know, keychain. "I don't want to use keychain because of some reason personally." ---> And what's that personal reason of yours?

Comment: Save the data in the user's iCloud account using CloudKit.

Comment: @rmaddy  thanks for your answer. How about if the user did not login in the iCloud account?

Comment: Then you can't save data to iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the details to a file and export that file using the Share extension in iOS application. Whenever the application is installed again then the app can import the data again from that file.

This is just a workaround but I strongly recommend Keychain in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser .
But how about if another also uses Share extension ?

Comment: May be you can encrypt the data and then write to the file. This way it will not be readable to other application or other user. If you user symmetric encryption in this case then you can store the symmetric key only in the keychain and when the file is imported again decrypt the data with that same key saved in the key chain.

Comment: How can i export file to share extension ? When we share we have to use UIActivityViewController .
Could you give me some sample code pls ?